# JavaScript action run file not change url path

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make my form check a SQL database, but when the form is submitted I want it to run a js file that pulls the database into a `const`.

But instead of doing this, it changes the URL.

How can I make it run the js script on the page, rather than changing URL?

Comment: use `XMLHttpRequest` with `form.onsubmit` handler

Comment: @SidVishnoi How would i use that on the form tag <form onsubmit="XMLHttpRequest" ?? im not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="some_identifier"/>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

this will prevent default form submission:

```
<script>
var form  = document.getElementById("myform");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
   console.log("send my data"); // do whatever you want to with data
   // use xmlHttpRequest here
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit event
});
</script>
```

xmlHttpRequest (xhr) example here:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_httprequest